# Limitations of developer version of websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I have been using the developer version of websphere mq to do some research for my organization.
It does not seem to have any licence cost or trial period.

I wanted to know what are the limitations of the developer version which would make it not suitable to be used in a production environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support available for developer edition as described here: http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibm-mq-advanced-for-developers. On production system you have to use licensed version.

Comment: Is it true that WebSphere Application Server for developers is available at versions 7 and 8.5.5 only ? i need to work on 8.5.0.2 need developer version